# How to get routes for a bus of low weight that doesn't qualify for tollroads but is heigh enough to collide with viaducts?

Tags: here-api, here-olp

I am using routing api in version 7.2 and trying to get routes by following request:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.32122157270602,4.567701386612513&waypoint1=52.939151549621045,17.300288086614863&mode=fastest;truck;tollroad:-3&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE&alternatives=2&height=3.2
```

but I get response  NoRouteFound.
The vehicle that is travelling by this route is a bus. The height of this bus is 3,2 meter.
To avoid collision with any viaducts I passed parameter "truck" so that I can use parameter "height" and set it to 3,2. The request doesn't find any viable routes because it avoids tollroads with strict weight. In practice the driver does not have to pay for this road because the vehicle is not that heavy so the request should return some routes.

Is there any more parameters that I can specify so that I find routes matching my criteria or do you have any other idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the driver does not have to pay for this road because the vehicle is not that heavy then why you calculate avoids tollroads with strict weight?

When you shouldn't to pay for toll roads however you can use toll roads for a  driving without payment.

But Router show you that the combination of restrictions "avoid strictly toll" + "high <= 3.2m" is impossible.

BTW

Please use this router playground calculator https://demo.routing.ext.here.com/ - there you can see that for given origin and destination any way you should to pay toll (at least in Poland country) for even transport mode "car" although weight is light.

Comment: Let me clarify - the driver doesn't have to pay for some parts of the route, but still has to pay for expressway which we want to avoid. When I choose "car" instead of "truck" the proposed routes are good. But I want to make sure that the car doesn't collide with tunnels for instance, so I want to specify height but I can't for car. So how can I get routes for "car" with height specified?